# Magento Dataflow import issues german

Tags: import, dataflow, germany

I have a pretty big problem with the dataflow import. I am now trying for days to import a CSV in my shop but i just can't get it to work. I guess that I'm using the wrong attributes.

These are my Attributes of the CSV:

> "SKU","Name","Hersteller","Packungsgröße","Geschmack","Gesamtgewicht (inkl. Verpackung)","Farbe","Größe","Produktmenge Netto","Referenz Menge","Referenz Einheit","Produkteinheit","Bild","Produkttyp","Listen-Einkaufspreis (Netto)","Listen-Verkaufspreis (Brutto)","Rabattklassen","Beschreibung","Steuerklasse","EAN-Nummer"

So if there is someone that could help me with this, that would be great. I have the Magento DE 1.9.0.1

Comment: Can´t you do an export first with the mapped tables and then see what the names in your database are? I always run an export of a few products and then use this .csv template to do the import again

Comment: @Thomas you should make this a answer, already see that there are some required field missing!

Answer (score 2):

As @Thomas already points correctly. Create a export and fill as much fields as possible.

Magento import will also complain about some required fields at the moment.

The first row needs to contain field names, second to many rows should contain your products.

Answer (score 1):

Can´t you do an export first with the mapped tables and then see what the names in your database are? I always run an export of a few products and then use this .csv template to do the import again.

So export first and then check your import file and adjust it to the export and import it then again.